# Паралельный вызов тойже функции из разных потоков

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Здравствуйте, вопрос очень прост: если из двух потоков, например в цикле, вызывается одна и таже функция, то будет ли задержка исполнения в отличие от тех же двух потоков, но с вызовом тела вмето самой функции?

Имхо, что команды для этой функции находятся где-то в памяти, и обращение к этому участку памяти не вызовет задержек (за исключеним случая если в процессоре одно ядро).

Очень надеюсь, что не ошибся в подаче вопроса. И заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос в целом некорректный, невозможно в системный вызов "стартани мне этот тред, детка" передать какое-то там "тело", всегда передается указатель на функцию.

Далее, судя по тексту вопроса, вы пытаетесь с компилятором поиграть в игру, "Я умею оптимизировать лучше тебя". Это - сильное заявление.

Довожу до вашего сведения, что в современных компиляторах C++ директива inline привела к генерации на сайте Стандарта языка вот [такой простыни](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions) противоречивых утверждений.

Из всего вышесказанного следует, что оптимизировать следует конкретный код, вооружившись профилировщиком и собрав статистику.

Если же вы просто ищите для себя Самый Лучший Стиль Написания кода - пишите так, чтобы код понял даже ваш коллега с IQ 80, набранный по объявлению позавчера, что подразумевает повышенный уровень структурирования кода и избегания простыней - если какой-то этап работы функции можно вынести в отдельную функцию (и покрыть тестами) - сделайте это, не стесняйтесь.

Answer (score 0):

Если взять абстрактную функцию в абстрактном коде, то вряд ли будет какая то задержка - абстрактному процессору все равно, какой код выполнять.

Другое дело, если в функции есть что то интересное - например, мютекс для синхронизации или доспуп к общему ресурсу. И вот тут может быть все что угодно.

Но если не смотреть на это все, нужно помнить, что у современных процессоров есть кеш - кеш данных, кеш кода. Если какая то функция постоянно выполняется, то она попадает в кеш кода, и если не будет вытесненно другим кодом, то будет находиться там достаточно долго и обращение к нему будет достаточно быстрым.